# LogbackConfigListener is failed to start in Spring 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring, logback

***Error*** - **org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file**

I am getting this error after adding logback config listener within web.xml.

I am using the following dependencies -

```
    <logback.version>1.2.9</logback.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-ext-spring</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>logbackConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/resources/logback.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.web.LogbackConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I have added **logback.xml** config for logging within **/src/main/resources/** location.

It would be great if there is anyone who can assist me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You like the suspence don't you? What is happening that doesn't happen? You dump some configuration without any error/result and expect us to know what is wrong? one thing I see is that it is old, very old and I doubt it is adapted for newer logback versions. Why do you need this anyway?

Comment: I have given the error as question title, I got. I have just got the one line error. Ok, I am updating the question

Comment: IT won't work regardless as this is for JavaEE and not JakartaEE. I also don't see why you would need it in the first place as the logback.xml will be loaded anyway by logback itself.

Comment: Yes. I know that logback should be loaded by logback itself. But its not working somehow

Comment: You don't need the listener to have the configuration loaded. just ditch the listener it won't work anyway. Also Spring 3 is old, so I assume Spring Boot 3. Which uses a newer version of Logback which you are managing back to an old unsupported version.

Comment: It is Spring 3 which is too old. But I need to integrate with it

Comment: You are aware that Spring 3 (or anything below 5.3) isn't supported anymore. I don't see why you would need this listener in te first place. If you `logback.xml` is in `src/main/resources` it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: If our file is already there the `/resources/logback.xml` is the wrong location, that should be `classpath:/logback.xml` instead.

Comment: Nothing worked. I tried to resolve in different ways

Comment: What have you tried as that isn't clear. As stated from what you posted here the location should be `classpath:/logback.xml` if that doesn't work it either isn't in the place you state or there is another error (and judging from the code there should be more information on the cause) so please post the actual logging output instead of a single line.